# What's the difference between subscribing to a Board vs subscribing to a card?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-boards

Will subscribing to a Board provide the same notifications as if you subscribed to every card within a board?  If not, what is the difference in functionality here?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's the same thing except:

- You will automatically subscribe to new cards added to the board.
- You won't see the eye symbol on every card if you're subscribed to the board.

From [this card](https://trello.com/card/board-and-list-subscribe/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1260) on the trello development board:

> #### Board and List Subscribe
>
> People are looking for a way to get notified of all actions on a given
> card, list, or board, without being assigned to it. Subscribing will
> do that.
>
> You can also subscribe to a list from the list menu (upper right
> button). You'll get notified of all actions that happens to cards in
> that list. The list will show a subscribe icon, but cards in that list
> won't show the icon unless you've subscribed to them.
>
> You can subscribe to a board from the board menu. It will add a
> subscribe icon to the board title. Like lists, it's not going to add
> an icon to every single card on the board.
>
> Permissions: You won't be able to subscribe to something unless it's
> on a board you can see. If you switch a board from public to private,
> people subscribed to it won't get notifications and it won't show up
> in your subscriptions list.

And here's from the [trello blog](http://blog.trello.com/board-and-list-subscribe-desktop-notifications-edit-comments-and-more/) introducing this feature:

> Subscribing to a card lets you get notifications as if you were added
> to it. When we launched it back in May, people loved it. The biggest
> feedback we received was that people wanted the ability to subscribe
> to whole boards and individual lists. We admit we were a bit hesitant
> — that’s a lot of notifications, at least for us. But there are some
> cases where it makes sense. Sit back and imagine…
>
> Let’s say you are on a Trello board shared by two other roommates.
> It’s filled with household tasks, upcoming bills and rent, grocery
> needs, etc. There’s not much activity so you want to know about
> everything that’s going on. Subscribing to every card would be a…
> chore, so you subscribe to the whole board. But you find that you
> don’t really need to know that Steve finished washing the dishes. You
> really only need to know about what to do next, so you just subscribe
> to the “New” list. Next thing you know, you’re out grocery shopping
> and hey look, you get a push notification on your iPhone or Android
> device. ”Get butter” was added to the list. You pick up a dozen boxes
> and return home where everyone thanks you profusely.
>
> Anyway, you get the idea. (Also you might want to cut back on the
> butter…)
>
> We’re excited to announce the launch of board and list subscribe. We
> can’t guarantee that it will make you the hero of your household, but
> we hope you find it useful. How does it work? To subscribe to a board,
> just click the “Options” button, then select “Subscribe”. To subscribe
> to a list, click the menu button in the list header, and select
> “Subscribe”. Now you can sit back and see changes without having to
> click through to every board.